# Specify port number in TCP client socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am writing an TCP client socket using C/C++.
  How could I specify certain port number in my client socket?
  Say the client socket is going to have two connections with the same server, 
  and the second connection should use the same local(client side) port number 
  to connect. How could pass the parameter into my code?

local port number is decided right after connect()? Or is it stored in the sock_new=socket()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to bind() the socket to a particular client-side port, but I don't know why you would need to do so; what is wrong with having the second connection use a different client-side port than the first one?  They will both connect to the same server-side port, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say the client socket is going to have two connections with the same server, and the second connection should use the same local(client side) port number to connect.

Not possible. Something about the tuple {source IP, source port, target IP, target port} has to be unique, to identify the connection.

What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear.
The second connection starts right after the first one terminated.
So I think it can still access to the same port.(since the first connection is closed)

Comment: Well you could try saving the local port of the first socket (with `getsockname()`, and binding the second socket to the same local port, after setting `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket(s), but the rules of TCP dictate a `TIME_WAIT` period between two succesive uses of an outbound port to the same target so it almost certainly won't work. Sounds like you should just keep the first connection open. Use a connection pool.